# Swipe app out of recent tasks in Android 6.0 but not kill the app process?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

The app(pkg:com.demo.app) service is foreground.

Before Android 6.0, when I swipe an app out of the recent tasks, the display log is:

```
04-11 19:44:34.337 1003-2301/? D/ActivityManager: for debug: forceStopPackage[pkg:com.demo.app,userId:0], caller[pid:23919,uid:1000]
04-11 19:44:34.337 1003-2301/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.demo.app appid=10238 user=0: from pid 23919
04-11 19:44:34.337 1003-2301/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 11059:com.demo.app/u0a238 (adj 2): stop com.demo.app
```

In Android 6.0, it is not. The app process is still alive.

How to explain this?